# SlickGrid integration tutorials or alternatives?

Tags: javascript, remote-objects

After scouring the web for hours I have been unable to find a tutorial that covers how to integrate SlickGrid into Salesforce. So far, I have found a few questions on StackExchange, the developer forums, and DeveloperForce YouTube videos that endorse it, but no one seems to have documented how to successfully implement it.

So far, I have rendered a grid in a VF container window sans sidebars, headers, html and body tags, but my goal is to keep both the header and sidebar visible. I have also pulled account information into the grid via SF Remote Objects.

Also, most of the content I have found dates back to 2013, so I am wondering if the community has found better methods by which to achieve this.

Any guidance of where to go next is much appreciated. I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Im not sure what slickgrid did but consider angularjs framework to render your grids . sample here http://www.oyecode.com/2013/06/getting-started-with-angularjs-on.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you for the Guidance @CloudHugger. SlickGrid allows for data entry in a form that is identifiable to those who have prior knowledge of Microsoft Excel. My goal is not only to display the information, but allow users to edit the grid easily as well.